# I am trying to parse data from all pages. Only the first page is parsed

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup, pagination

I am trying to parse data from all pages. Parsing ends after the first page. What could be the problem?
I use pagination with the use of a regular expression.

The first page of the site and others differ in the html code, so I have to create two different functions main_1 and main_2 for the first and other pages.

If you try to run only the main_2 function, nothing will work. .CSV file will not be created.
help me please.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import re


def get_html(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    if r.ok:
        return r.text
    print(r.status_code)


def writer_csv(data):
    with open('tesr.csv', 'a') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow((data['name'], data['url'], data['price']))


def get_data_page(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    trs = soup.find_all('tr', class_='cmc-table-row')
    for tr in trs:
        tds = tr.find_all('td')

        try:
            name = tds[1].find('a', class_='cmc-link').text.strip()
        except:
            name = ''

        try:
            url = 'https://coinmarketcap.com' + str(tds[1].find('a', class_='cmc-link').get('href'))
        except:
            url = ''

        try:
            price = tr.find('td', class_='cmc-table__cell--sort-by__price').find('a').text.strip().replace('$', '')
        except:
            price = ''

        data = {'name': name,
                'url': url,
                'price': price}
        writer_csv(data)


def main_1():
    url_1 = 'https://coinmarketcap.com/'
    get_data_page(get_html(url_1))


def main_2():
    url_2 = 'https://coinmarketcap.com/2/'

    while True:
        get_data_page(get_html(url_2))

        soup = BeautifulSoup(get_html(url_2), 'lxml')

        try:
            pattern = 'Next '
            url_2 = 'https://coinmarketcap.com' + str(soup.find('ul', class_='pagination').find('a', text=re.compile(pattern)).get('href'))
        except:
            break


main_1()
main_2()
```

Comment: From the [terms of use](https://coinmarketcap.com/terms): You agree that you will not: Use or introduce to the Service any data mining, crawling, "scraping", robot or similar automated or data gathering or extraction method, ....

Comment: Just an FYI that there is an [API](https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/)